android studio console errror
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(12063): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2206 GL error 0x502
i have restart android studio, my emulator, swipe emulator data, reinitialise my emulator an android studio

For what it's worth, that's GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
